# Xamarin.Forms: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: MyApp.UI.Base...'

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application. The project structure is somewhat more complex than in a regular Xamarin.Forms solution.

I have my platform-specific projects:

- MyApp.Android
- MyApp.iOS
- MyApp.UWP

I have a .net standard library project for the .xaml page definitions:

- MyApp.UI (this is referenced by the platform-specific projects)

I have a .net standard library project for the .xaml page base classes:

- MyApp.UI.Base (this is referenced by MyApp.UI)

I have a PageBase class in MyApp.UI.Base.
Let's say I have Login.xaml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<base:PageBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
               xmlns:base="clr-namespace:MyApp.UI.Base;assembly=MyApp.UI.Base" ...>
...
</base:PageBase>
```

The type in Login.cs is also correct:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Login : PageBase
{
// ...
}
```

When I compile the solution, I get the following error:

Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: MyApp.UI.Base, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.'

This error seems totally wrong, I tried other solutions, like deleting the .vs folder or restoring nuget packages but none of them worked.

Can I **not** have base classes of xaml pages from different assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the project MyApp.UI.Base **was not** referenced from the MyApp.UWP project. Adding a reference solved the issue. I guess the error was right, just not that exact.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution - this fixed the issue for me